# Enviar checkbox como arreglo en ajax y procesarlo en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema a la hora de enviar el valor de varios checkbox a través de ajax.

Por ejemplo tengo:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='1' />
<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='2' />
<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='3' />
<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='4' />
<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='5' />
```

y para enviarlo por ajax hago lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'entrega': $("#p_entrega").val(),
                'recibe': $("#p_recibe").val(),
                'visto_bueno': $("#visto_bueno").val(),
                'ids[]': $('[name="ids[]"]').serialize()
              },
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/reportes/acta/agregarActa",
        success : function(data) {
          console.log(data[0].id_acta);
        }
    });
```

Pero al momento de procesarlo en PHP llega de la siguiente manera:

```
Array ( [0] => ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3&ids%5B%5D=4&ids%5B%5D=5 )
```

- **¿Existe alguna manera de que llegue como arreglo?**
- **¿Existe manera de transformarlo en un arreglo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno leyendo un poco mas la documentación de jquery llegué a encontrar la función `serializeArray()` que crea un arreglo de objetos, listo para ser codificado como una cadena JSON, de esta manera en la llamada ajax envío una cadena **JSON** y la decodifico en **PHP** para obtener un arreglo.

Los cambios en la llamada ajax anterior son:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',

        data: { 'entrega': $("#p_entrega").val(),
                'recibe': $("#p_recibe").val(),
                'visto_bueno': $("#visto_bueno").val(),
                'ids': JSON.stringify($('[name="ids[]"]').serializeArray())
              },
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/reportes/acta/agregarActa",
        success : function(data) {
          //console.log(data[0].id_acta);

        }
    });
```

Y para procesarlo en **PHP** lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST["ids"],TRUE));
```

Con lo que obtuve la siguiente salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ids
            [value] => 139
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ids
            [value] => 135
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => ids
            [value] => 145
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery por defecto convierte los parametros de `data` a un string, utiliza `processData` y el `contentType` según el tipo de datos:

[Documentación .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
[Código de .ajax() en Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js)

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    processData: false,
    // en caso de ser necesario
    // contentType: ...
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tambien puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
//Aquí buscamos todos los inputs que tengan una clase llamada; checkBoxGroup
var a = document.querySelectorAll("input.checkBoxGroup");
//Ahora vamos hacer uso del Prototype de JS para digamos recorrer todo lo que se ha generado desde la variable a y lo devolvemos a la variable ids_
var ids_ = Array.prototype.map.call(a,function(x){ return x.value; });
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'entrega': $("#p_entrega").val(),
                'recibe': $("#p_recibe").val(),
                'visto_bueno': $("#visto_bueno").val(),
                'ids': ids_ //aqui aplicamos los ids_ en Array
              },
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/reportes/acta/agregarActa",
        success : function(data) {
          //console.log(data[0].id_acta);

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```